# How to convert a Ruby object to JSON from a File?

Tags: ruby, json, github-linguist

I'm trying to use the Linguist gem: https://github.com/github/linguist

My code is:

```
require 'linguist'

filePath = ARGV
langDetails = Linguist::FileBlob.new(filePath)
puts langDetails
```

That outputs: `#<Linguist::FileBlob:0x007faf93b17200>`

However, when I do `puts langDetails.language`, I get

```
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@linguist/gems/github-linguist-2.10.15/lib/linguist/file_blob.rb:39:in `stat': can't convert Array into String (TypeError)
  from /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@linguist/gems/github-linguist-2.10.15/lib/linguist/file_blob.rb:39:in `mode'
  from /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@linguist/gems/github-linguist-2.10.15/lib/linguist/blob_helper.rb:294:in `language'
  from ./linguist.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong. Ideally I want the data back as a JSON object. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the source. FileBlog is saying `File.stat(@path).mode.to_s(8)` but `@path` is an array. `filePath` needs to be a path string, but ARGV is an array.

Perhaps you meant `ARGV[0]`?

Comment: Great call! Thanks for the find. But now how do I get the results as a JSON object?

Comment: What results do you expect as a JSON object and why? I have never used Linguist but I don't see anything about that in the docs. It tells you what language your file is in. That's a string. How you expect Linguist to take you from "a Ruby object to JSON" is outside my understanding. You were getting an error, I explained it.

Comment: If you want to turn a Ruby object to JSON, use the `to_json` method. But then I don't see what Linguist has to do with it.